# SQL show individual results as % of total

Tags: sql, select

Hoping someone could please help me with this question.

i have the following dataset in a table called t_customerdata:

| Customer | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| John | $100 |
| Paul | $150 |
| Linda | $50 |
| Karen | $95 |

What i want is to show, in the same table, each person's % of total balance.

So, basically, my aim is for the table to look like this:

| Customer | Balance | %ofTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | $100 | 25.3164 |
| Paul | $150 | 37.9746 |
| Linda | $50 | 12.6582 |
| Karen | $95 | 24.0506 |

I have tried the below code, somewhat naively hoping it might work, but it hasn't as SQL forces me to group by balance as well, which means the calc always returns 100%:

```
select
customer,
balance / sum(balance) as [%ofTotal]
from t_customerdata
group by
customer,
balance
```

Comment: what is your db ? is balance column a string ?

Comment: balance is a double. i am using a datacube my company created for data mining purposes, and reading off an excel spreadsheet on a shared drive location. it uses a form of CubeSQL hence i dont have the normal SQL CTE or window functions

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do that :

```sql
select *, balance*100.0 / (select sum(balance) from t_customerdata)
from t_customerdata


custommer   balance (No column name)
john    100 25.316455696202
paul    150 37.974683544303
Linda   50  12.658227848101
karen   95  24.050632911392
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function. For example:

```
select *, 100.0 * balance / sum(balance) over() from t_customerdata
```

Comment: sorry should have clarified, the data mining software i am using uses a form of CubeSQl, and i dont have the usual window or CTE functions available

Comment: If your database engine does not implement window functions then @Steven's answer is the best one. On the flip side if CubeSQL is running on top of SQLite, then you do have access to window functions.